# Fail hudson build if loglevel set too low

Tags: java, maven, hudson

I'd like to fail the build for live jobs of some java applications if their log4j loglevel is set too low.

Is this possible? I'm guessing what I'm maybe looking for is some kind of hudson plugin which could grep the log4j.properties. Or is this something I should somehow be doing in maven?

Comment: Why not just set the log level to the right level?

Comment: You could parse the log configuration provided by your application (and even correct it, as Peter said), but keep in mind that there might be situations in which log configuration can be changed at runtime (e.g. when using an application/web server).

Comment: @PeterLawrey Because I'm not the developer of the applications

Comment: Ah sorry, I understand now - yes, correcting the loglevel would be even better. The problem I've got though is that the applications have been setup to use parameterized logging, but there are a number of naughty developers who replace the parameter placeholder in their application with a hardcoded value and forget to change it back before committing.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple utility app that will configure it's log4j system from the target properties file. After that using the Log4j API you can loop through all appenders and check the log level. If its too low - throw an exception. Run this tool before building the app. If it fails - Jenkins job will fail.